# Between 2 dates form Validation Access. I've tried many different things and nothing works

Tags: ms-access

I'm having a hard time figuring out why my code isn't working with this front end form validation rule regarding a range of dates.

So far I've tried many different solutions stated below that have kept yielding me the same error. The data I've been inputting is 03/29/2021 and it's giving me an error when it should be in that range.

Does someone know why and how to go about fixing it? Thank you!

```
Between #1/1/2012# and Date()

Not IsNull([Date]) And Between #1/1/2012# And #1/1/2024#

Not IsNull([Date]) And Between #1/1/2012# And Date() (I would like to use this one the most to eliminate as much human error as possible)

Not IsNull([Date]) And Between #01/01/2012# And #01/01/2024#

Not IsNull([Date]) And Between #01/01/2012# And Date()

Not IsNull([Date]) And Between #01/01/2012# And >= Date()
```

Comment: Advise not to use reserved words as names. Date is a reserved word.

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Your preferred condition works for me. However, must enter something in control, just tabbing through doesn't trigger. Can set field in table as Required and Access will nag users to provide data before record commits. Use control LostFocus event. And/or form BeforeUpdate event to validate record data.

Comment: Where did your previous and identical question go?

Comment: @hansup the error message is just something i created to catch if the validation rule was broken

Comment: @june7 agreed however, for this project it has to be named that unfortunately. What I meant by it isn't working is that the validation rule even with all of those either just doesn't work and only accepts the range dates or only ranges between 1/1/XXXX and 2/23/XXXX in the required range when it should be 1/1/XXXX and 12/31/XXXX in the required range.

Comment: @gustav Hey sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and when you answered my thread yesterday I believed that it closed it off from other people from answering it because I hadn't received any more help other than the one you gave me (which I appreciate). Therefore, I created this thread to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

This setting for the validation rule works:

```
Between #01/01/2012# And Date() And Not Is Null
```

Comment: Yes it does logically, everything makes sense however, if I were to input 3/30/2021 it spits back my validation rule message back to me. Which is why it makes me think that it's only taking in 1/1/XXXX to 2/23/XXXX even if I give it a static input range like 1/1/2012 to 12/31/2022 it will not accept 3/30/2021 which should be in that range.

Comment: No it doesn't; something else must be going on. I can't replicate that error. It works nicely here. So double-check ...

Comment: Agreed, I don't know what that could be though. Is there like a setting where I need to turn something on for it to be a range greater than 1 year? I have the format as Short Date.

Comment: No. The format is for display only.